# batch to check if terminal can ping servers or not

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I wrote a batch but it doesnt work at all:

```
set THEFILE=ip_list.txt

if exist result.txt del result.txt

::read %THEFILE% and loop through each line
for /F %%A in (%THEFILE%) do (


    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET counter=1
    FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`ping %%A`) DO (
      SET result%counter%=%%F
      SET counter=%counter%+1
    )
    ECHO %result1%
    ECHO %result2%
    ECHO %result3%
    echo %result9% >> result.txt
    ENDLOCAL

    echo ******************************************* >> result.txt
)
```

inside of ip_list.txt :

```
8.8.8.8
4.4.4.4
```

I need to get ip adresses if not %100 loss occurs..

I need a quick help in my code..

Comment: well, the first thing I see is you need to use !counter! with delayedexpansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set THEFILE=ip_list.txt
if exist result.txt del result.txt
for /F %%A in (%THEFILE%) do (
  call :IsPingable %%A && (
    Echo %%A is pingable ) || (Echo %%A is not pingable)
)

exit /b

:IsPingable <comp>
ping -n 1 -w 3000 -4 -l 8 "%~1" | Find "TTL=">nul  
exit /b
```